Showing that a solid triangle is Jordan measurable
I'm trying to solve the following exercise:
Let $A,B,C$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Show that the solid triangle with vertices $A,B,C$ is Jordan measurable.
I attempted to prove this statement by taking an inner and outer cover for the triangle where the vertices of the inner and outer cover will be points in the neighbourhoods of $A,B,C$:
Let $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be three points such that they are the vertices of the triangle $\triangle(ABC)$.
$\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists$ points $( \underline{x_i} , \underline{t(x_i)} )$  and $(\overline{x_i} , \overline{t(x_i)})$ in the neighbourhood of points $A,B,C$ such that they form an inner and an outer triangle.
We can represent the vertices of the inner triangle as $\underline{A},\underline{B},\underline{C}$ and the vertices of the outer triangle as $\overline{A},\overline{B},\overline{C}$
As $\underline{A}$ and $\overline{A}$ is in the same neighbourhood of $A$, Then, $\overline{A} - \underline{A} < \epsilon^{1/n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. idem for B and C.
Now we need to find $m(\triangle(\overline{ABC}))-m(\triangle(\underline{ABC}))$
we separate the triangles into small boxes and find the differences between inner and outer triangles:
$m( \prod_i^n[\overline{x_i} , \overline{t(x_i)}[)-m(\prod_i^n[\underline{x_i} , \underline{t(x_i)}[) = $
$m\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \left( \overline{x_i} , \overline{t(x_i)} \right) - \left( \underline{x_i} , \underline{t(x_i)} \right) \right)$
$\leq \prod_{i=0}^n \epsilon^{1/n}=\epsilon$
Therefore the difference of measure between the inner and outer triangles is $\epsilon$
Therefore, the solid triangle with vertices A,B,C is Jordan measurable.
I think my writing is not very rigorous and I'm not sure the idea is correct either. What can my mistakes be and how could I potentially improve my proof?

As a first step, can you show that the (exterior) Jordan measure of a segment is $0$?  This and some basic facts would then imply your result.
For this, consider a segment $AB$, $A=(0,0)$, $B=(x,y)$.  You can cover it with a rectangle of sides $x$, $y$, so its measure is $\le x y$. We can do better: divide it into $n$ equal segments. Each can be covered by a rectangle of sides $\frac{x}{n}$, $\frac{y}{n}$. We get the measure $\le n \cdot \frac{x y}{n^2} = \frac{x y}{n}$. Now take $n\to \infty$.

Why is the measure of a segment being 0 important here?

Oh, there is a theorem claiming that a (bounded) subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable Jordan if and only if its boundary has Jordan measure $0$. But we could avoid  it and try to prove directly. However, at some moment you need to show that whatever intersects the boundary ( if the rectangles are small) is of small measure.

I think your idea is incorrect.
Because you can't be sure that the outer triangle and inner triangle are elementary sets.
This means we cannot guarantee that a solid triangle in the plane is elementary measurable,which is actually the core of what we aim to prove in this context.
To solve this question, we need to proceed in a manner similar to how we handle problems in calculus.

A

B
There are two ways to approximate the area of a triangle using rectangles.
Just divide one side of the triangle into n equal intervals.(Note that every triangle can be divided into two right triangles, so it suffices to consider the measure of a single right triangle.)
The goal is to demonstrate that, as the approximating sets are refined to become increasingly precise, the lower and upper bounds converge to the same value.If we makes the approximating sets A,B increasingly fine,we can hope that these two bounds eventually match.
It's easy to prove as the number n of intervals for the division approaches $\infty $.

Thank you for the feedback!
